# How to give link of a button to a text in label

Tags: asp.net, button, hyperlink, label

I have a label as:

```
<asp:Label  ID="lblwc" runat="server" BackColor="#CCFF66" 
BorderColor="#009900" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Italic="True" 
Font-Names="Rockwell Condensed" BorderStyle="None" ForeColor="Black"> 
</asp:Label>
```

and its .cs defination is:

```
lblwc.Text = "Thank You for Registration," +" " + name.Text +  " | <a href=\"\">login</a> " ;
```

What i want to do is give link in href="" but the link is not the link to a page but link to a button.
Help!!!

Comment: do you want to run button code using hyperlink?

Comment: please create a link to a named anchor by using the name attribute (or the id attribute). please refer http://www.tagindex.net/html/link/a_name.html

Comment: Where is the button exist, in the same page or different page.can you be little more clear on your question please?

Comment: @AkshayP yes i want to trigger the  button on clicking the text.

Comment: @Anna.P the button exist on the same page.I have two button sign-in and signup on the same page.The signup when clicked opens a light-box containing registration form.when i click the register-me button ,i display the message "Thank you for registration Anna | login".Now when i click the login. i should be able to call the sign-in button.I hope now the scenerio is pretty much clear.THANK YOU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I've understood the question but i suppose you want an hyperlink that need to fire a button click event

`lblwc.Text = "Thank You for Registration," + " " + name.Text + "<a onclick=\"document.getElementById('myBtnID').click();\">login</a>";`

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
<a id="my-link" href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('myButtonId').onclick();">Login</a>
```